# In phpStorm, how to put javascript breakpoint in a php file

Tags: php, javascript, phpstorm

I am new at the software phpStorm.

When I edit a html file, I can put break point on the javscript part, by clicking on the left of the code editor.

However, when I edit a php file, it doesn't work. It works only to put a break point on the php part of the code.

How can I put javascript break point on my php files?

Comment: As always in IDE, when you click on the bar which is on the left of the code, you can add breakpoint. I've edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: If you have mixed php and js in a single file it is doubtfully you can do that

Comment: Not 'as always'. Some have interactive debugging, some don't. Some do it for some languages but not others. Your question is *highly* specific to the IDE you're using.

Comment: Yes, I've mixed php javascript and html...

Comment: @Hamish i disagree with the highly specific. Ive yet to see an IDE for PHP that doesnt have interactive debugging.

Comment: @Hamish for programming. You never specified for javascript. but regardless, the IDE's i use, which are used for PHP, javascript and html, all have the breakpoint bar on the left

Comment: Read the question. "I can put break point on the javscript part".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [official documentation page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+and+JavaScript+code+at+the+same+time+in+PhpStorm) (2015), in section 5, it is written that there is no such possibility:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Add a `debugger;` line to your JavaScript code. For example:

```js
alert("First.");
debugger; // Trigger a breakpoint.
alert("Second.");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to debug the Javascript in PHPStorm (and not the Browser), you can do so by using the remote javascript debugging option.

A blog explaining this is here:
http://tiger-fish.com/blog/using-phpstorm-debug-javascript

Short version: in the Javascript Debug configuration you set the start URL to the php file. And you map the *.js you want to debug.

Comment: Wonderful finally I can debug everything in one place ! It is really annoying for me use the integrated debugger in chrome ( nice but too small ... and the shortkeys are different from phpstorm ... )

Comment: Link is broken. Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150901222803/http://tiger-fish.com/blog/using-phpstorm-debug-javascript